# What programs account for structural alignment of different parts of distant homologs which have significant structural differences?

Tags: sequence-alignment, proteins, protein-structure, 3d-structure, structural-biology

If there is a need to perform structural alignment of different parts of distant homologs, which program one should use?

Since distant homologs often have significant structural changes, meaning the assumption of a similar physico-chemical environment for aligned residues would be violated.

Any program/tools or suggested reference will be a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: You _might_ want to check out [TCoffee's Espresso](http://tcoffee.crg.cat/apps/tcoffee/do:expresso) as it does a structure based alignment (requires structures to be given/exist in PDB). However, in my hands it has always performed less than ideally.

Answer (score 1):

TM-align has some options to do this, see for example https://zhanglab.ccmb.med.umich.edu/TM-align/help.html.

TM-align is similar to TM-score but the alignment is purely structural.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `progressiveMauve` (http://darlinglab.org/mauve/user-guide/progressivemauve.html), or `bubbz` (https://www.cell.com/iscience/fulltext/S2589-0042%2820%2930409-0)